# Is it possible to print errors?

Tags: go, aws-lambda

For example such code:

```
os.Stderr.WriteString(rec.(string))
```

But this will not show as an error:
[image: aws lambda monitoring]

I know that I can panic after logging and catch it on API Gateway (against sending stacktrace to the client) - no other ways? [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-programming-model-errors.html) is not mention anything like that.

Comment: In Node.js, we can simply do `console.log("whatever")` and it will show up in CloudWatch logs for the function... with no errors graphed.

Comment: `console.log("whatever")` looks like log statement, not as an error logging.

Comment: Well, where do you plan to consume the error messages? If not the log file, why don't you just push whatever you want to an SNS topic and listen to that?

Comment: I want to see errors in Lambda console when I here.

Comment: You can view the log/errors in console... at least for Node, but presumably all other languages too. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-logging.html

Comment: Yep, but somebody looking at the graph will think that no errors occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not possible. I assume, you're looking at the metrics in Amazon CloudWatch

> AWS Lambda automatically monitors functions on your behalf, reporting
>   metrics through Amazon CloudWatch. These metrics include total
>   invocations, **errors**, duration, throttles, DLQ errors and Iterator age
>   for stream-based invocations.
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-metrics.html

Now, let's see how do they define errors

> Metric "Errors" measures the number of invocations that failed due to errors in the
>   function (response code 4XX).

So, if you want to see the errors on that graph, you have to respond with the proper codes. If you're concerned about exposing the error stacktrace, here is a good read [Error handling with API Gateway and Go Lambda functions](https://hackernoon.com/error-handling-with-api-gateway-and-go-lambda-functions-fe0e10808732). The basic idea there is about creating a custom lambdaError type, meant to be used by a Lambda handler function to wrap errors before returning them. This custom error message

```
{
  "code": "TASK_NOT_FOUND",
  "public_message": "Task not found",
  "private_message": "unknown task: foo-bar"
}
```

will be wrapped in a standard one

```
{
  "errorMessage": "{\"code\":\"TASK_NOT_FOUND\",\"public_message\":\"Task not found\",\"private_message\":\"unknown task: foo-bar\"}",
  "errorType": "lambdaError"
}
```

and later on mapped in API Gateway, so, the end client will see only the public message

```
{
  "code": "TASK_NOT_FOUND",
  "message": "Task not found"
}
```